# PreFetching data apollo

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

I've been playing with apollo and refetching, and got question.

I've implemented a feature to prefetch data onMouseOver, and when I mouse over on that "component" it makes two same requests at same time. Any ideas why ?

[image: Network Request]

```
const prefetchData = (id) => () => {
    client.query({
      query:FETCH_DATA,
      variables:{id},
    })
  }
<Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} onMouseOver={prefetchData(id)} to={`/posts/${id}`}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be the mouse event bubbling up from the `<Link />` dependent on the dom element you mouse over within the `<Link />`.

Comment: Yeah, reading about event bubbling now, changed to onMouseEnter, seems fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Changing from onMouseOver to onMouseEnter did the trick.

```
<Link style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} onMouseEnter={prefetchData(id)} to={`/posts/${id}`}>
```